# web page looks different when changing the responsive look on developer tools

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a web page I started and currently just trying to get the nav bar to be responsive, I've got all the media query tags in but when I'm looking at how it looks in different screen sizes on developer tools, sometimes it will look exactly how I want it to and other times it will look wrong.

I haven't changed anything in the code but when I'm going through the different screen options it will just switch between and I'm not sure why so I don't know whether the code is wrong or if it's just developer tools adjusting?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```js
const navSlide = () => {
  const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
  const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links');
  const NavLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links li');


  burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
    //toggle Nav
    nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');


    //Animate Links
    NavLinks.forEach(link, index); {
      if (link.style.animation) {
        link.style.animation = '';
      } else {
        link.style.animation = `NavLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7 + 3}s`;
      }
    };

    //burger animation
    burger.classList.toggle('toggle');

  }, )
}

navSlide();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}


/*navigation top bar*/

.nav {
  background-color: #2b2929;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 8vh;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.logo {
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  font-size: 22px;
}

.nav-links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 30pc;
}

.nav-links li {
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-links :hover {
  color: rgb(0, 204, 255);
}

.nav-links a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.burger {
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.burger div {
  width: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 5px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .nav-links {
    width: 60%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
  body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  .nav-links {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    height: 92vh;
    top: 6vh;
    background-color: #2b2929;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 50%;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
  }
  .nav-links li {
    opacity: 100%;
  }
  .burger {
    display: block;
  }
  .footer {
    padding-bottom: 100px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:768px) {
  body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
}

.nav-active {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}

@keyframes navlinkfade {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(50px)
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Sue Allerton</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body>
  <nav class="nav">

    <h1 class="logo">Sue Allerton</h1>

    <ul class="nav-links">
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About Me</a></li>
      <li><a href="collections.html">Collections</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="burger">
      <div class="line1"></div>
      <div class="line2"></div>
      <div class="line3"></div>

    </div>
  </nav>
  <section class="container">
    <div class="main">
      <p>let your imagination run wild</p>
    </div>
  </section>

  <footer class="footer">

    <div class="social">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/sueallerton2/">Facebook</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/author_sue95/">Instagram</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.goodreads.com/author/show/16440673.Sue_Allerton">Goodreads</a></li>
      </ul>

    </div>

  </footer>




  <script src="app.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm looking at how it looks in different screen sizes on developer tools, sometimes it will look exactly how I want it to and other times it will look wrong.

You should mention on which screen size it looks different and what you mean by how exactly you want it to look. Also it seems like `link` is not defined because you are using `forEach` on a collection and that is an Array method. You can convert the collection to an array first

```
const NavLinksArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(NavLinks)
```